# Tor doesn't work with urllib2

Tags: configuration, python

I am trying to use tor for anonymous access through privoxy as a proxy through urllib2.

System info: Ubuntu 14.04, recently upgraded from 13.10 through dist-upgrade.

This is a piece of code I am using for test purposes:

```
import urllib2


def req(url):
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": "127.0.0.1:8118"})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    return opener.open(url).read()

print req('https://check.torproject.org')
```

The above outputs a page with a `sorry, but you don't use Tor` message.

As for my configurations:
**/etc/tor/torrc**

```
ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
HashedControlPassword 16:B3B0BA631D41D6FE601488FC7A9A2E80AB7815580C1C78F2865F30F63B
```

**/etc/privoxy/config**

```
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .
```

`$ sudo netstat -ntap | grep tor` outputs:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1045/tor        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1045/tor        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.94:56736         85.17.190.83:9002       ESTABLISHED 1045/tor        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.94:60558         50.7.110.118:9001       ESTABLISHED 1045/tor        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.94:43206         62.210.236.135:443      ESTABLISHED 1045/tor
```

`$ sudo netstat -ntap | grep privoxy` outputs:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8118          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      887/privoxy
```

And yet, all requests are received at the server with my actual IP

Comment: Do you have privoxy running, and if yes did you nano /etc/privoxy/config and uncomment the # forward socks5t line? Privoxy will run all the HTTP traffic threw socks5 which should go threw tor if it's set up right.

Comment: a good example of the code you may be looking for.                                   https://gist.github.com/iwtbotiwtwot/0995e1342b2650487a0df0a7201a5e25

Comment: this one - https://gist.github.com/iwtbotiwtwot/15f7ed4c53b8c36e4b5b5f437a17dfc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `127.0.0.1:8118` as a proxy URL (in a nutshell) with `http` as your protocol. You should use `https` instead.

Related:

- [Tor doesn't work with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220494/tor-doesnt-work-with-urllib2)
- [Python urllib2 > HTTP Proxy > HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248895/204634)